# Could anybody give an explicit example of a unilateral Laplace transform that converges conditionally in a strip?

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

For example, a Laplace transform integral that converges absolutely for Re(s)>2 but converges only conditionally for 1 < Re(s) < 2.
Stuff like that.
I don't mean conditional convergence only on the boundary line either.
I can't think of any examples...

Comment: Try things like $e^u \sin(e^{u^2}) 1_{u > 0}$

Comment: Thanks, but I would like an exact proof.

Comment: Um, that Laplace integral converges absol. for Re (s)>1 since the sine term has modul. less than one. Maybe you meant for it to converge conditionally on 0 <Re (s)<1 or something?

Comment: Ah, now I see. Integrating e^t*sin (e^(t^2)) from 1 to 100 on Wolfram Alpha gives something close to 1, so maybe it doesn't diverge. (If not for the sine term then...)

Comment: I tried doing that, but I end up getting more integrals that I'm not sure converges absolutely or at all.

Comment: Integrate by parts $\int_1^a (e^{-su} \frac{e^{-u^2}}{2u}) (2u e^{u^2} \sin(e^{u^2}))du$ and let $a \to \infty$

Comment: Not really, integration by parts shows it converges for every $s$

Comment: Oh, I see. That would give an absolutely converging integral for all s, thanks for the comment :)